# TcpRewrite -> TCP Retransmissions Как редактировать TCP пакеты?

Tags: сеть, http, сокет, ssl, tcp

Добрый вечер.
Перехватил запрос регистрации приложения Android. Я так понял данные передаются через tcp ssl.
https://www.sendspace.com/file/960w74 - оригинальный запрос регистрации .pcap ([Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)).
С помощью [WireEdit](https://wireedit.com/) изменил email (пакет 42) - https://www.sendspace.com/file/0wdaib
С помощью [tcprewrite](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/tcprewrite) отправил изменённые пакеты данных

```
tcprewrite --infile=regtrue1.pcap --outfile=output12.pcap
```

Запросы не сработали, на выходе получил данный файл output12.pcap - https://www.sendspace.com/file/f9cmu4
В которых видны ошибки TCP Retransmissions в пакетах 44,45
Как мне заменить email и редактировать данные чтобы запросы сработали? И через что их отправлять? Как правильно редактировать TCP SSL пакеты?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Лучше добавьте все нужные данные в вопрос, не у всех есть нужные программы под рукой.

Comment: Добавил программы.

Comment: Не ссылки на программы, а покажите ваши пакеты в вопросе. Какой вы изменили, где там емейл был и т.д. Так больше шансов, что кто-то ответит на вопрос. Или скриншоты приложите.